# Creating waitable objects in Python

Tags: python, sockets

I more or less know how to use select() to take a list of sockets, and only return the ones that are ready to read/write something.  The project I'm working on now has a class called 'user'.  Each 'user' object contains its own socket.  What I would like to do is pass a list of users to a select(), and get back a list of only the users where user.socket is ready to read/write.  Any thoughts on where to start on this?

Edit:  Changed switch() to select().  I need to proofread better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have your `User` class implement a `fileno(self)` method which returns `self.thesocket.fileno()` -- that's the way to make `select` work on your own classes (sockets only on windows, arbitrary files on Unix-like systems).  Not sure what `switch` is supposed to me -- don't recognize it as a standard library (or built-in) Python concept...?